# Track changes on worksheet, copy cell that is not the active cell in active cell row and record value

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I was able to adapt the below formula for my needs and is working well.  I do see though I need to add a line to help lock in calculations that happen later.  How can it be written to copy a value in col “R” of the cell changed active row and continue the logic to place in col 18 on LogDetails worksheet?

Code Located in worksheet:

---

```
Option Explicit
Public OldValue As String
         
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim sSheetName As String
    
    sSheetName = "Capital"
    
    Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).value = ActiveSheet.Name
    Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).value = Environ("username")
    Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).value = Target.Address(0, 0)
    Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 10).value = Now
    Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 14).value = OldValue
    Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 15).value = Target.value
                 
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Selection.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Multiple cell selections are not allowed on this sheet", vbCritical
        ActiveCell.Select
   Exit Sub
End If
   
    On Error Resume Next
    OldValue = Target.value
 
End Sub
```

---

Appreciate and insights…!

Comment: `Public OldValue As String` Why dim as a string? Are there never numbers or dates selected? My advice: `Public OldValue As Variant`

Comment: As line 3 at the top of the worksheet module, add this: `Public OldColumnRValue As Variant` And then in the `Worksheet_Change` event, add this line under the others: `Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).offset(0, 18).Value = OldColumnRValue` And in the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event, add this line near the bottom: `OldColumnRValue = Range("A1")(Target.Row, 18).Value`

Comment: Please let me know if that works for you and if so I'll add it as a proper answer that you can accept.

Comment: Does that work for you?

Comment: sorry Ricardo, i posted before i was finished. i can use Public OldValue As Variant, may be a better approach.  any insights how to add into code: if any cell on sheet is changed it will also record Col R of that same row regardless of active cell col.  then have it get placed on the logdetails ws on the same row as the other recorded data.  i plan to put this into Offset(0, 18) on logdetails

Comment: I'm not Ricardo. The suggestions I gave should do precisely what you are describing. Have you tried them?

Comment: sorry, learning the site.  that works brilliantly.  thank you Excel Hero!

Comment: If I write my suggestions up as a proper answer will you accept it?

Comment: yes of course...

Comment: OK. I've posted my answer for you!

Comment: appears i need to go a step further and get the 'current value' of col R as well.  how would you go about getting the current value of col R.

Comment: My answer... posted below... does just that. It gets and save the value in Column R of the selected cell-row. Please accept the answer.

Comment: it is getting the oldcolumnRvalue correctly and putting in the logdetails sheet where i want.  what i am also looking for now is newcolumnRvalue,  when the active cell changes it impacts col R and i would like both sets of values to compare later.  i would put this  in .Offset(, 19) = NewColumnRValue.  if it built into the one below, ill stop for the night and try again tomorrow.

Comment: I can help you with that, but it is really a new question. Please accept the answer for the original question.

Comment: ok, i will submit new to get other value.  how do i accept answer?

Comment: Just ckick on the checkmark directly to the left of my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Hit me up tomorrow for the next question.

Comment: morning, to properly place question should i put new question(s) in here or fill out new?

Comment: Good morning. You should ask a separate and new question. In that question you can refer to this one.

Comment: does not appear as though i linked, so here in the topic of new question.  Track changes on worksheet, copy active cell change Column Header & NewColumnValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below incorporates the suggestions I made to you by way of the comments under your question.

I've also simplified the code a bit...

```
Option Explicit
Public OldValue, OldColumnRValue

     
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)        
    Application.EnableEvents = False        
        With Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
            .Offset(1) = ActiveSheet.Name
            .Offset(, 1) = Environ("username")
            .Offset(, 2) = Target.Address(0, 0)
            .Offset(, 10) = Now
            .Offset(, 14) = OldValue
            .Offset(, 15) = Target
            .Offset(, 18) = OldColumnRValue
        End With                     
    Application.EnableEvents = True        
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)    
    If Selection.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        OldValue = Target
        OldColumnRValue = Range("A1")(Target.Row, 18)
        Exit Sub
    End If    
    MsgBox "Multiple cell selections are not allowed on this sheet", vbCritical
    ActiveCell.Select    
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

First let's not repeat ourselves. Use the `With` keyword to work with an object. Then we will add a dynamic offset in our selection change to record the value from the R column of the selected row. We will use that in your LogDetail to place the value in column 18.

```
Option Explicit
Public oldValue As Variant
Public currentRvalue As Variant
         
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim sSheetName As String
    
    sSheetName = "Capital"
    
    With Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
        .Offset(1, 0).Value = ActiveSheet.Name
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = Environ("username")
        .Offset(0, 2).Value = Target.Address(0, 0)
        .Offset(0, 10).Value = Now
        .Offset(0, 14).Value = oldValue
        .Offset(0, 15).Value = Target.Value
        .Offset(0, 18).Value = currentRvalue
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Selection.Cells.Count > 1 Then
            MsgBox "Multiple cell selections are not allowed on this sheet", vbCritical
            ActiveCell.Select
       Exit Sub
    End If
   
    oldValue = Target.Value
    currentRvalue = Target.Offset(0, 18 - Target.Column).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: appreciate this simple approach.  as a novice, consolidation isnt there yet for me and this helps me moving forward.